# Angular 2. Observable is not defined

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I'm trying to use `Observable` and `ChangeDetectionStrategy` in order to inform the others components about changes happend. Unfortunately Observable object `addItemStream` is undefined. What is wrong here?

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Input }          from '@angular/core'
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router }  from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: 'bp-header',
    templateUrl: 'app/header.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class HeaderComponent {
    @Input() addItemStream: Observable<any>;
    public isActive: number;
    public language: string = "en";
    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.isActive = 1;
     }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.addItemStream.subscribe(() => {
        this.setLanguage; // application state changed
        this.cd.markForCheck();
       })
    }
    public setLanguage = (language: string) => {
        if (this.language === language) { return }
        else { this.language = language };
    }
    public setActive(active: number) {
        if (this.isActive === active) return;
        this.isActive = active;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you subscribe to it. I usually do it in the constructor. However, when the component initializes first the stream is undefined so just initialize it in your constructor:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  this.addItemStream = new Observable<any>();
}
```

Comment: If the Observable is passed to the component as an Input it definitely matters. If you try to subscribe to it when it is still undefined it simply won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You are subscribing to the `Observable` in `ngOnInit`.
Since it is an `Input` the `Observable` (and all other `Inputs`) will be `undefined` at that point.

Try subscribing to it in `ngAfterViewInit`.
Alternatively, put in a service. That makes your life (and sharing the `Observable`) a lot easier.

Comment: Do you mean this: ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.addItemStream.subscribe(() => {
            this.setLanguage; 
            this.cd.markForCheck();
        })
    }

Comment: I did updated my code above, but there is the same error.

Comment: It should work but it depends when and where you create the Observable. Without more context code it is difficult to say what the issue is. In any case: I would recommend putting the Observable in a service. It's the better solution.